# Proof involving expected values

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be IID random variables with mean $\mu$, standard deviation $\sigma$ and finite fourth moment. Prove by induction that

$E([\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \mu)]^{4}) = nE((x_i-\mu)^{4})+6{n\choose 2}\sigma^{4}$.

First, I can rewrite this equation as follows (since they are IID, each $x_i$ is the same distribution as any other):

$E([\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \mu)]^{4}) = nE((x-\mu)^{4})+6{n\choose 2}\sigma^{4}$.

Note the small change in the first part of the RHS.

Base case: $n=1$

$E((x - \mu)^{4}) = (1)E((x-\mu)^{4})+6{1\choose 2}\sigma^{4}$. But ${n \choose k} = 0$ when $k > n$, so we get the desired result.

Induction Hypothesis: Suppose this result holds for $n=1, ..., k$. We show it holds for $k+1$. Now I plug in $n=k+1$, as follows:

\begin{align*}
E([\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} (x_i-\mu)]^{4}) = E([\sum_{i=1}^{k} (x_i-\mu) + (x-\mu)]^{4}).
\end{align*}

Using the binomial theorem with $a = \sum_{i=1}^{k} (x_i-\mu)$ and $b = 
(x-\mu)$, as well as the fact that $E[X+Y] = E[X]+E[Y]$, and $E[XY] = E[X]E[Y]$ (from independence), I have:

\begin{align*}
E([\sum_{i=1}^{k} x_i-\mu]^{4}) + 4E([\sum_{i=1}^{k} x_i-\mu]^{3})E(x-\mu)+6E([\sum_{i=1}^{k} x_i-\mu]^{2})E([x-\mu]^{2})+4E([\sum_{i=1}^{k} x_i-\mu])E([x-\mu]^{3})+E([x-\mu]^{4}).
\end{align*}

From the induction hypothesis I can say that the first term + the last term is equal to 
\begin{align*}
kE([x-\mu]^{4})+6{k\choose 2}\sigma^{4} + E([x-\mu]^{4}) = (k+1)E([x-\mu]^{4})+6{k \choose 2}\sigma^{4}.
\end{align*}
This looks similar to what I want, I just need a way to obtain $6{k+1\choose 2}\sigma^{4}$.

$\textbf{Edit}$: I think that $E(x-\mu) = 0$, so the second term in the binomial expansion vanishes. So I just need to deal with the terms $6E([\sum_{i=1}^{k} x_i-\mu]^{2})E([x-\mu]^{2})+4E([\sum_{i=1}^{k} x_i-\mu])E([x-\mu]^{3})$.

Comment: Necessarily by induction? 'Cause the direct proof is... well, direct.

Comment: Yes, I'm self-studying and the problem asks by induction. I thought it was direct as well, but had trouble doing it by induction.

Comment: I may be a bit slow... But I don’t even understand your first equation. With $i$ as a sum index on the LHS, $i$ alone on the RHS. And do you have hypothesis on the $x_i$?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited it. I left important information out. The $x_i$'s are IID, so the single $x_i$ can be re-written as $x$, for example.

Comment: $(a+b)^4=a^4 + 4 a^3 b + 6 a^2 b^2 + 4 a b^3 + b^4$ is a good start

Comment: I've edited it -- does it look ok?