# Expected values of IID random variables

Tags: probability

I'm trying to make sure I am understanding the following properties:

For $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ IID random variables with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$,

$E(c) = c$, where $c$ is any constant

$E(X_i) = \mu$,

$E(\mu) = \mu$ (from the first equality)

$E(X_i - \mu) = E(X_i)-E(\mu) = \mu-\mu = 0$

Are these correct? Additionally, I'd like to think about

$E([X-\mu]^{2})$, and

($\sum_{i=1}^{k} [X-\mu])^{3}$

Where $X$ is any of the $X_i$'s (since they are identically distributed, I can say $X_i = X$, for all $i$, correct?)

Self-studying these concepts, any guidance very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done is correct. $E(X-\mu)^{2}=E(X^{2}-2\mu X+\mu^{2})=EX^{2} -2\mu EX+\mu^{2} =(\sigma^{2}+\mu^{2})-2\mu^{2} +\mu^{2}=\sigma^{2}$. In general $E(X-\mu)^{2}$ is always the variance of $X$. T0 calculate $E( \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}(X_i-\mu))^{3}$  you have to expand $(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}X_i-\mu)^{3}$ as $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k}\sum\limits_{l=1}^{k} (X_i -\mu)(X_j-\mu)(X_l-\mu)$. [ I have used the following: $\sigma^{2}=EX^{2}-\mu^{2}$ by definition . Hence $EX^{2}=\mu^{2}+\sigma^{2}$]. How do we compute $E(X_i -\mu)(X_j-\mu)(X_l-\mu)$?. The value is $0$ if any two of $i,j,l$ are  distinct and it is $E(X-\mu)^{3}$ if $i=j=l$. You can calculate $E(X-\mu)^{3}$ by expanding the cube (using Binomial Theorem).

Comment: Thanks. Having trouble understanding why $E[X^{2}] = (\sigma^{2} + \mu^{2})$, though.

Comment: Also, that last part is the cube of the entire sum, not just the summand.

Comment: I have added another line to my answer. @mXdX

Comment: @mXdX Sorry that I ddin't read the last part correctly. I have revised my answer.

Comment: So then I can say $\sum_{i=1}^{k}\sum_{j=1}^{k}\sum_{l=1}^{k} (X_i - \mu)(X_j-\mu)(X_l - \mu) = E(X-\mu)^{3}$?

Comment: Would you mind looking at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3083618/proof-involving-expected-values ? It's the same concepts, I'm trying to simplify a string of expected values. I feel that I am a couple steps away from the answer.

Comment: @mXdX There are $k$ terms in the sum with $i=j=k$. So you will get $kE(X-\mu)^{3}$.  For the fourth power you can use a similar argument.

Comment: Wouldn't I get  [$\sum_{i=1}^{k} (X_i - \mu)]^{2} = (kX-k\mu)^{2} = k^{2}x^{2}-2k^{2}x\mu+k^{2}\mu^{2} = k^{2}(\sigma^{2})$. So for the cubic example, wouldn't it be $k^{3}E(X-\mu)^{3}$?